# How often do Cloud Build Node.js versions update?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I couldn't stomach purchasing the $150 for GCP's support service for this one question. I'm just looking to understand the schedule for Cloud Build Node.js versions. It's still stuck on Node.js v10.10 and my projects are starting to require higher versions to build. According to Cloud Build's changelog, I don't believe the Node.js version has updated in years. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official [Github repository](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-cloudbuild):

> Our client libraries follow the [Node.js release schedule](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/). Libraries are compatible with all current active and maintenance versions of Node.js.

So, this means it should work with Node.js 12 and the updates should be more constant. In addition to that, in [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/building/build-nodejs#building_with_npm_or_yarn), it says that if you are using a [Cloud Build config file](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config), you can use Node.js 12, so the Node.js' latest version should be compatible with Cloud Build.

To summarize, by the repository, it should follow Node.js schedule. However, in case you think this is not occurring, I would recommend you to raise a bug on the [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190802&template=0) - it's free, by the way - so they can assess this.

Comment: It seems the other advice I received on using other node versions was incorrect, and I never found the documentation you linked. Thank you very much!